# Google Marketplace Add-on Listing Traffic Drop After Store Listing Update?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Has any other Google Marketplace app developer experienced a traffic drop after making updates to their app's Store Listing? On July 7 I made some small changes to the availability of my app by removing some countries where the app was available for sale. I made no changes to my app's description or title, just where the countries where it's available to be installed. I forget which countries I removed, but it was just a handful that aren't profitable for us to operate in. Most of my traffic comes from the US. After making the update my traffic dropped about 30%.

[image: Traffic Change by Channel]

However, the traffic drop is across the board, including the US and all other countries the where the app is available (not just the ones I removed). Note I re-added Brazil, which is why that traffic is up.

[image: Traffic Change by Country]

The original change was approximately on July 7. I made a further change on July 28 in attempt to get the listing re-indexed (if that was the issue). I added just one character to the Detailed Description of my listing without changing any other part and saved it. Since then it appears that my traffic dropped further.

[image: Traffic Over Time]

The most puzzling thing is that my app seems to still rank #1 for all the same keywords it did before the changes. I can't figure out what would have caused such a noticeable drop in traffic without a change to the ranking of the app. My best guess is it's a indexing or caching issue where my changes have to be propagated to all users of the Marketplace and the listing does not appear in some circumstances.

Are Google Workspace Marketplace updates updated & indexed immediately or do they take time to propagate in the store?

Comment: Is that last sentence your real question? Is it really a proper programming question? [ask]

Comment: @rob thanks for the clarification. I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: There's a short-lived cache; after a few minutes all users will see the change. How are you measuring the traffic? Could this be related to the migration to Google Analytics 4?

Comment: Thanks @AlejandroTamalet, this is helpful. The screenshots above are from my GA4 account. It's unfortunate the issue seemed to have coincided with the switch to GA4 as it did introduce a new variable, but I did see the drop in my Universal Analytics data prior to those reports being stopped. I also see the issue in my install data which I track from my database.

Comment: Changing the name or countries of an app does not affect how it is ranked. The main factors are the number and score of reviews, installations and usage. Could it be that one of those countries you removed was responsible for the missing traffic?